# How can I check if a string is null or empty in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, string, powershell, null

Is there a built-in `IsNullOrEmpty`-like function in order to check if a string is null or empty, in PowerShell?

I could not find it so far and if there is a built-in way, I do not want to write a function for this.

Comment: hop this helps http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/01/06/checking-for-a-null-or-empty-string/

Comment: Well you're using .NET, so can't you call `String.IsNullOrEmpty`?

Comment: It's 2024 and the answer is still as Jon Skeet said: [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($myString) works in PowerShell v7.4.0

Answer (score 690, accepted):

You can use the `IsNullOrEmpty` static method:

```
[string]::IsNullOrEmpty(...)
```

Comment: I like this way more as it is obvious what it does regardless of your Powerhsell knowledge -which would make sense for non-Powershell programmers.

Comment: I guess you can just do !$var

Comment: One thing to be aware of with PowerShell is that null strings passed to a commandlet or function don't stay null. They get converted to empty strings. See the Microsoft Connect bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/861093/nullstring-value-is-not-preserved-when-passed-to-functions.

Comment: Consider [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(...) for validating empty spaces as well.

Comment: @ShayLevy Careful with the `!`. That only works in newer versions of PowerShell. `!` is an alias for `-not`

Answer (score 864):

You guys are making this too hard.  PowerShell handles this quite elegantly e.g.:

```
> $str1 = $null
> if ($str1) { 'not empty' } else { 'empty' }
empty

> $str2 = ''
> if ($str2) { 'not empty' } else { 'empty' }
empty

> $str3 = ' '
> if ($str3) { 'not empty' } else { 'empty' }
not empty

> $str4 = 'asdf'
> if ($str4) { 'not empty' } else { 'empty' }
not empty

> if ($str1 -and $str2) { 'neither empty' } else { 'one or both empty' }
one or both empty

> if ($str3 -and $str4) { 'neither empty' } else { 'one or both empty' }
neither empty
```

Comment: @pencilCake Yes, that what I'm saying and the example above shows it in action.  What the test won't check for is IsNullOrWhitespace().

Comment: I agree with your answer, but it is only correct in combination with @ShayLevy. When dealing with strings, `$null` is not the same as `''`. For most use cases you can assume that they are; this is the discretion of the programmer. You may also want to treat `' '` as empty/null, which can be done with `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(' ')` or `' '.Trim()` ... which one reads easier? I like the simplicity/elegance of coding with PowerShell, but sometimes you need to be more specific. ***Note:*** *Use `[string]::` + `<tab>` to "tab" through all the available methods of `[string]`*

Comment: @VertigoRay See my first comment above where I recommend using `IsNullOrWhitespace()` for that scenario.  But after 11 years of scripting with PowerShell, I find I need that string test *very rarely*.  :-)

Comment: This is the dangerous practice in both _Powershell_ and _Javascript_ if the variable type is not restricted. Consider this: 
`$str1=$false`
or
`$str1=@(0)`

Comment: @Dmitry That's a fair point .  You can use restricted types in PowerShell fairly easily `[string]$str = $false` gives you `False`.   So these test could be `if ([string]$str) { ... }` if you want to be sure.

Comment: "KeithHill. 
Sorry that is still unsafe, since your intention is not clear. 
When you use [string]::IsNullOrEmpty, you are absolutely clear. 
IMO, Powershell is a strangest creation - most of the times it is overabundantly rich, but still missing essentials. -isNullOrEmpty predicate is one of them...

Comment: If this reply is correct, when i don't understand the following behaviour:
    `$minor=$matches['minor'];if($minor) { $minor="00" }; if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($minor)) { $minor="00" }`
It doesn't step into the first if, but into the second. Sorry, i couldn't figure out how to add nicely formatted multi line code in a comment

Comment: For the first `if` you want `if (-not $minor) { $minor="00" }`.  When `$minor` is null or an empty string it will eval to `$false` in a conditional.  But it appears you want the `if` statement to execute so invert that to make the conditional eval to `$true`.

Comment: Also `$str1=0`, in eg will return "empty". But `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($str1)` will return false. However `[string]$str1=0` will return "not empty" in the example. As in JS you need to beware of implicit type conversion when using `if($str1)`

Comment: @dmitry nailed it with understanding what you want.  And often "truthy" or "falsy" is good enough, and you can wave away a lot of other things in a bounded context. A string array _could_ have `0` in it, but if it's not _supposed_ to, it's not necessarily _your method's_ job to care. (But also, the potential bug could be bad enough to justify being extra defensive.)

Answer (score 60):

In addition to `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty` in order to check for null or empty you can cast a string to a Boolean explicitly or in Boolean expressions:

```
$string = $null
[bool]$string
if (!$string) { "string is null or empty" }

$string = ''
[bool]$string
if (!$string) { "string is null or empty" }

$string = 'something'
[bool]$string
if ($string) { "string is not null or empty" }
```

Output:

```
False
string is null or empty

False
string is null or empty

True
string is not null or empty
```

Comment: Nice point. `If` clause internally converts everything inside the parenthesis to single boolean which means `if($string){Things to do for non-empty-nor-null}` or `if(!$string){Things to do for empty-or-null}` without explicit conversion `[bool]` would be enough.

Comment: These implicit conversions are the most dangerous thing. You need to make sure that you have exactly string type. Consider $string=@(0) - quite possible to occur...

Answer (score 27):

If it is a parameter in a function, you can validate it with `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty` as you can see in this example:

```
Function Test-Something
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$UserName
    )

    #stuff todo
}
```

Comment: This is by far better approach. Although, it is not exactly a solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 26):

Personally, I do not accept a whitespace ($STR3) as being 'not empty'.

When a variable that only contains whitespaces is passed onto a parameter, it will often error that the parameters value may not be '$null', instead of saying it may not be a whitespace, some remove commands might remove a root folder instead of a subfolder if the subfolder name is a "white space", all the reason not to accept a string containing whitespaces in many cases.

I find this is the best way to accomplish it:

```
$STR1 = $null
IF ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($STR1)){'empty'} else {'not empty'}
```

Empty

```
$STR2 = ""
IF ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($STR2)){'empty'} else {'not empty'}
```

Empty

```
$STR3 = " "
IF ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($STR3)){'empty !! :-)'} else {'not Empty :-('}
```

Empty!! :-)

```
$STR4 = "Nico"
IF ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($STR4)){'empty'} else {'not empty'}
```

Not empty

Comment: .Net has String::IsNullOrEmpty for your purpose.

Answer (score 15):

Many good answers here; let me offer a **pragmatic summary** with **PowerShell-idiomatic solutions**:

Given a variable `$str` that may contain `$null` or a *string* (or any *scalar*):

```bash
# Test for $null or '' (empty string).
# Equivalent of: [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($str)
$str -like ''

# Test for $null or '' or all-whitespace.
# Equivalent of: [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($str)
$str -notmatch '\S'
```

Note: If `$str` can be a *collection* (array), use the type-agnostic solutions at the bottom.

- Using the string-only [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like) operator implicitly coerces the LHS to a *string*, and since `[string] $null` yields the empty string, both `'' -like ''` and `$null -like ''` yield `$true`.
- Similarly, the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-match` / `-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operators, as *string-only* operators, coerce their LHS operand to a string, and `$null` is treated like `''` in this conversion.

  - `\S` is a regex escape sequence that matches any *non*-whitespace character (it is the negated form of `\s`).
  - `-match` / `-notmatch` perform *substring* matching by default (and only ever return *one* match), so if `\S` matches, the implication is that at least one character that isn't a whitespace character is present.

---

**Caveat**:

Given PowerShell's dynamic typing, you may not know the type of the value stored in a given variable ahead of time.

While the techniques above work predictable with `$null`, `[string]` instances, and other types that are *non-enumerable*, ***enumerable* values (other than strings) may yield surprising results**, because if the LHS of `-like` and `-notmatch` are enumerables (loosely speaking: collections), the operation is applied to *each element*, and instead of returning a single Boolean value, the *sub-array of matching elements* is returned.

In the context of a conditional, the way an array is coerced to a Boolean is somewhat counterintuitive; if the array has just *one* element, that element itself is coerced to a Boolean; with *two or more* elements, the array is always coerced to `$true`, irrespective of the element values - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375). For instance:

```bash
# -> 'why?', because @('', '') -like '' yields @('', ''), which
# - due to being a 2-element array - is $true
$var = @('', '')
if ($var -like '') { 'why?' }
```

if you **cast a non-string enumerable LHS to `[string]`**, PowerShell stringifies it by space-concatenating its (stringified) elements.
This is also what happens *implicitly* when you call `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()` or `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, because their parameter is `[string]`-typed.

Thus, the **type-agnostic equivalents of the above** - using the stringification rules described - are:

```bash
# Test for $null or '' (empty string) or any stringified value being ''
# Equivalent of: [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($var)
[string] $var -eq ''

# Test for $null or '' or all-whitespace or any stringified value being ''
# Equivalent of: [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($var)
([string] $var).Trim() -eq ''
```

Answer (score 14):

PowerShell 2.0 replacement for `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is `string -notmatch "\S"`

("**\S**" = any non-whitespace character)

```
> $null  -notmatch "\S"
True
> "   "  -notmatch "\S"
True
> " x "  -notmatch "\S"
False
```

Performance is very close:

```
> Measure-Command {1..1000000 |% {[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace("   ")}}
TotalMilliseconds : 3641.2089

> Measure-Command {1..1000000 |% {"   " -notmatch "\S"}}
TotalMilliseconds : 4040.8453
```

Answer (score 8):

I have a PowerShell script I have to run on a computer so out of date that it doesn't have [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), so I wrote my own.

```
function IsNullOrWhitespace($str)
{
    if ($str)
    {
        return ($str -replace " ","" -replace "`t","").Length -eq 0
    }
    else
    {
        return $TRUE
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `.Trim()` instead of listing types of whitespace? So it would be `$str.Trim().Length -eq 0`

Comment: `$str -notmatch '\S'` should suffice and covers _all_ types of whitespace, not just spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 7):

```
# cases
$x = null
$x = ''
$x = ' '

# test
if ($x -and $x.trim()) {'not empty'} else {'empty'}
or
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($x)) {'empty'} else {'not empty'}
```

Answer (score 4):

When a boolean is expected, PowerShell will use `$true` for variables not null, zero or empty.

Hence, the cleanest approach to validating whether a string is **not** Null or Empty is:

```
if ($str) { }
```

Or the opposite condition to validate a string **is** Null or Empty:

```
if (!$str) { }
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.4#simple-if-check

**Example 1:**

```
$str = $null
if ($str) { "1: String = $str" } else { '1: Null or Empty' }

$str = ""
if ($str) { "2: String = $str" } else { '2: Null or Empty' }

if ($undeclaredVar) { "$undeclaredVar" } else { '3: Null or Empty' }

$str = 0
if ($str) { "4: String = $str" } else { '4: Null or Empty' }

$str = 1
if ($str) { "5: String = $str" } else { '5: Null or Empty' }

$str = -1
if ($str) { "6: String = $str" } else { '6: Null or Empty' }

$str = "Gold"
if ($str) { "7: String = $str" } else { '7: Null or Empty' }

output:
1: Null or Empty
2: Null or Empty
3: Null or Empty
4: Null or Empty
5: String = 1
6: String = -1
7: String = Gold
```

To take a similar approach when using ForEach-Object (%), use a script block with just the variable. This could be the current object ($_ / $PSItem), another variable or a parameter.

**Example 2:**

```
"a", -1, 0, $null, 1, 2, , '', "", 3 | ? { $_ }

output:
a
-1
1
2
3
```

Validating whether a property is Null or Empty is even easier. Just use ? + property name:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{ Name = 'Gold' } | ? Name | % { "Valid name = $_" }
```

If you need to avoid **whitespace**, surround your variable with double quotes and `Trim()` it:

```
if ("$str".Trim()) { }
```

Most of the time, worrying about **whitespace** is not necessary, and the above Trim() is something I rarely use. If the above will run in high repetition, you can reduce your memory usage by using one of these instead:

```
If(([string]$str).Trim()) { }

# The below requires PowerShell 4 or above
if([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($str)) { }
```

**Example 3:**

```
$str = $null
if ("$str".Trim()) { "1: String = $str" } else { '1: Null or Empty' }

$str = ""
if ("$str".Trim()) { "2: String = $str" } else { '2: Null or Empty' }

if ($undeclaredVar) { "$undeclaredVar" } else { '3: Null or Empty' }

$str = 0
if ("$str".Trim()) { "4: String = $str" } else { '4: Null or Empty' }

$str = 1
if ("$str".Trim()) { "5: String = $str" } else { '5: Null or Empty' }

$str = -1
if ("$str".Trim()) { "6: String = $str" } else { '6: Null or Empty' }

$str = "Gold"
if ("$str".Trim()) { "7: String = $str" } else { '7: Null or Empty' }

$str = " "
if ("$str".Trim()) { "8: String = $str" } else { '8: Null or Empty' }

output:
1: Null or Empty
2: Null or Empty
3: Null or Empty
4: String = 0
5: String = 1
6: String = -1
7: String = Gold
8: Null or Empty
```

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the tangential shortcoming with [@KeithHill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747939/584676) not covering the *`IsNullOrWhitespace`* case, in PowerShell 7.1 and later we can use the [null-conditional member operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#null-conditional-operators--and-) to gracefully check if a string is null or whitespace without needing to first check that the string isn't `$null` ourselves, while avoiding the use of `[string]::IsNullOrWhitespace(string)`.

> **Note:** You can also do this with PowerShell 7.0 if you enable the `PSNullConditionalOperators` experimental feature:
>
> ```
> Enable-ExperimentalFeature -Name PSNullConditionalOperators
> ```

To use the `$str3` example from Keith's answer (and pretending the ternary operator doesn't also exist since 7.0 for clarity):

```
$str3 = ' '
if ( ${str3}?.Trim() ) {
  'not empty or whitespace'
} else {
  'empty or whitespace'
}
empty or whitespace
```

`.Trim()` is only invoked if `$str3` is a non-null value, otherwise `$null` is returned instead.

---

One thing to remember is that a question mark `?` is valid as part of a variable name. This is why we must *first* disambiguate the variable name by before applying the conditional-access operator like so: `${str3}`

---

Since I did mention the ternary operator earlier, *and* since this answer already centers around PowerShell 7.1 and later, you can simplify the code block above by using the ternary operator, removing the boilerplate `if/then/else` statement almost entirely:

```
${str3}?.Trim() ? 'not empty or whitespace' : 'empty or whitespace'
```

The [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) is a simplified `if/then/else` statement for basic conditionals. I don't want to muddy the waters too much here with nuances around it, but read it as "if the left side of the *lone* question-mark `?` is true, execute what is on the right side of the `?`, or else execute what comes after the colon `:`".

You can read more about the ternary operator in the [PowerShell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this in a pure PowerShell way would be to do something like this:

```
("" -eq ("{0}" -f $val).Trim())
```

This evaluates successfully for null, empty string, and whitespace. I'm formatting the passed value into an empty string to handle null (otherwise a null will cause an error when the Trim is called). Then just evaluate equality with an empty string. I think I still prefer the IsNullOrWhiteSpace, but if you're looking for another way to do it, this will work.

```
$val = null    
("" -eq ("{0}" -f $val).Trim())
>True
$val = "      "
("" -eq ("{0}" -f $val).Trim())
>True
$val = ""
("" -eq ("{0}" -f $val).Trim())
>True
$val = "not null or empty or whitespace"
("" -eq ("{0}" -f $val).Trim())
>False
```

In a fit of boredom, I played with this some and made it shorter (albeit more cryptic):

```
!!(("$val").Trim())
```

or

```
!(("$val").Trim())
```

depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional statement with both `IsNullOrWhitespace()` and `isNullOrEmpty()` static methods testing for white spaces or a null value. For example, before inserting into a `MySQL` database, I loop through the values I will enter and use the condition to avoid null or whitespace values.

```
// RowData is iterative, in this case a hashtable,
// $_.values targets the values of the hashtable

$rowData | ForEach-Object {
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.values) -and
        -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.values)) {
            // Insert logic here to use non-null/whitespace values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative adding 2 new [Script Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmembertypes?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to the [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0) instances using [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
Update-TypeData -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName IsNullOrEmpty -Value {
    return [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($this)
} -TypeName System.String

Update-TypeData -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName IsNullOrWhiteSpace -Value {
    return [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($this)
} -TypeName System.String

'hello'.IsNullOrEmpty()  # => False
''.IsNullOrEmpty()       # => True
' '.IsNullOrEmpty()      # => False
' '.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() # => True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a filter that converts empty strings to nulls, then you only would have to check for null.

```
filter nullif {@($_, $null)[$_ -eq '']}
```

Then you just need to pipe your value into it

```
('' | nullif) -eq $null
> True
('x' | nullif) -eq $null
> False
```

An even easier mrthod would be to use a regex

```
$null -match '^$'
> True
'' -match '^$'
> True
'x' -match '^$'
> False
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension of the answer from Keith Hill (to account for whitespace):

```
$str = "     "
if ($str -and $version.Trim()) { Write-Host "Not Empty" } else { Write-Host "Empty" }
```

This returns "Empty" for nulls, empty strings, and strings with whitespace, and "Not Empty" for everything else.