# PowerShell: Pass local variable to function

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell code:

```
function readConfigData
{
    $workingDir = (Get-Location).Path
    $file = ""

    if ($Global:USE_LOCAL_SERVER)
    {
        $file = $workingDir + '\Configs\Localhost.ini'
    }
    else
    {
        $file = $workingDir + '\Configs\' + $env:COMPUTERNAME + '.ini'
    }

    Write-Host 'INIFILE: ' $file

    if (!$file -or ($file = ""))
    {
        throw [System.Exception] "Ini fil är inte satt."
    }
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $file))
    {
        throw [System.Exception] "Kan inte hitta ini fil."
    }
}

readConfigData
```

How should I declare the local variable `$file` that can be passed to the function `Test-Path`.
My local variable $file get populated but then when I place it as argument to other function it's like it is out of scope.

I read the [about scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) article but wasn't able to figure it out.

Currently I get the error:

> INIFILE:  D:\Projects\scripts\Configs\HBOX.ini Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to
>   parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string. At
>   D:\Projects\freelancer.com\nero2000\cmd script to
>   powershell\script.ps1:141 char:27
>   +     if (!(Test-Path -Path $file))
>   +                           ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!$file -or ($file = ""))
```

should be replaced by

```
if (!$file -or ($file -eq ""))
```

You assign $file to an empty string in the first if clause and therefore your variable is empty in the Test-Path call.

Edit: Also there are some alternatives: [How can I check if a string is null or empty in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738634/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-powershell)

you could either use

```
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($file))
```

or even just

```
if(!$file)
```

Comment: Powershell uses -eq for the equals comparison. Not ==

Comment: Also, while it is true that initially an empty string is assigned to $file, $file is then immediately assigned one of two different values depending on the $Global:USE_LOCAL_SERVER variable. So it is not empty at the time that Test-Path is called.

Comment: But it is assigned to an empty string again in the first if-clause. But i can understand you confusion, my answer is not written clear enough

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you are unintentionally assigning a blank string to $file in your first `if (!$file ...` statement. That is really the root of your problem.

However, instead of:

```
if (!$file -or ($file = ""))
```

You could use this forumula, which I find explains itself better:

```
if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($file))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define a function `Get-ConfigFile` to retrieve the config and add a `switch` for local server:

```
function Get-ConfigFile
{
    Param(
        [switch]$UseLocalServer
    )

    $workingDir = (Get-Location).Path
    if ($UseLocalServer.IsPresent)
    {
         Join-Path $workingDir '\Configs\Localhost.ini'
    }
    else
    {
         Join-Path $workingDir ('\Configs\{0}.ini' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME)
    }
}
```

I would also use the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to join a path instead of string concatenations.

Now you can retrive the config file path using:

```
$configFile = Get-ConfigFile -UseLocalServer:$Global:USE_LOCAL_SERVER
```

And if needed, ensure that the file exists:

```
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $configFile))
{
    throw [System.Exception] "Kan inte hitta ini fil."
}
```

Note: 
[Get-Location](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113321) will give you the *current powershell path (working location)*, if you want to get the path where *your script is located*, use this instead:

```
$workingDir = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definitio
```