# Why is '^\S' not working for first character or NULL value?

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that is holding two values from a table (using `-expandproperty`)

```
$variable = "value1,value2"
```

I have a check to make sure `$variable` doesnt have any NULL/empty value returned

```
if(($variable.Split(",") | Where { $_ -match '^\S'}).count -lt 1)
{write "no value!"}
else
{write $variable}
```

but for some reason, even though `'^\S'` is supposed to ONLY check the first character/index for a whitespace, it outputs "

> no value

" condition result...it should be outputting

> value1,value2

instead...

not only that, but if the table column value is `NULL`, it doesnt recognize it and instead tried to output the second condition `write $variable`

why is that??

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code including the first line, and it outputs `value1,value2`

Comment: @trebleCode can you try setting $variable to NULL and try that?

Comment: When setting `$variable` to `$Null`, get a `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` error message. if setting the `Where` statement to use a lowercase s, it returns 'no value' but returns values with capital S

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string is not NULL or EMPTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008016/check-if-a-string-is-not-null-or-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to check for "null or empty" is to use the `[string]IsNulOrEmpty()` static method. something like this ...

```
$Var1 = "value1,value2"
$Var2 = ''
$Var3 = $Null

$Var1, $Var2, $Var3 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_
        [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)
        }
```

output ...

```
value1,value2
False

True
True
```

note that the final `$Null` did not produce a new line, while the 2nd item [an empty string] did.

Comment: THANK YOU! this is an even better solution!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

`\S` is nonwhite space.

`\s` is whitespace.