# PowerShell Where-Object query for empty or NULL contents between parentheses

Tags: powershell, filtering

My apologies if my question doesn't quite describe what I'm asking here! I'm not sure how to filter for field contents, or lack off, between braces/parentheses. My top search results return [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738634/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-powershell) article, which I don't think resolves my issue.

I'm trying to pull all users from MSOnline/AzureAD that have the Multi Factor Authentication option Disabled/not set. This fact is a little trivial, but it sets the context....

I have the below query which returns a test user I know doesn't have the StrongAuthenticationRequirements value configured.

```
> get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName test@contoso.com | select UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,StrongAuthenticationRequirements

UserPrincipalName DisplayName  StrongAuthenticationRequirements
----------------- -----------  --------------------------------
test@contoso.com  Test Account {}
```

I'm also able to run a query using Where-Object to find those that DO have the value set.

```
> get-MsolUser | where-object { $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements -like "*Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement*" } | select UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,StrongAuthenticationRequirements

UserPrincipalName DisplayName  StrongAuthenticationRequirements
----------------- -----------  --------------------------------
test@contoso.com  Test Account {Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement}
```

My question is; how do I run a non-user specific query to find all instances where the StrongAuthenticationRequirement field is "{}"?


Thanks in advance!

Comment: `StrongAuthenticationRequirements` is a collection. So it is empty when `$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -eq 0`.

Comment: @Compo: `{}` is how PowerShell's output-formatting system represents empty collections; try `[pscustomobject] @{ EmptyArray = @() }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `StrongAuthenticationRequirements` is a collection, an empty collection would have a `Count` value of `0`.

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object { $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -eq 0 } |
    Select UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,StrongAuthenticationRequirements
```

Comment: Fantastic!

An 'empty collection'; committed to memory.

Thanks a lot!