# Weird Coalesce Behavior

Tags: powershell

Ok, recently I was looking for a way to null coalesce in PowerShell, and I ran into this post: [Null coalescing in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623907/null-coalescing-in-powershell).

I saw the comment by @Zenexer, and was intrigued. Here was the syntax:

```
Clear-Host
#expected one
"Test 1: " + ("one", "two", 1 -ne $null)[0]
#expected two
"Test 2: " + ($null, "two", 1 -ne $null)[0]
```

This works perfectly. However, a co-worker (Walter Puckett) and I were very interested and did some more digging into the syntax and found some real weirdness.

Before I get into the weirdness, can anyone point to any documentation that explains this syntax?

```
## THE WEIRDNESS:

# it does not matter what the number is evidently
"Test 3: " + ($null, "two", 8675309 -ne $null)[0]

# reversing the comparison test breaks the coalesce
"Test 4: " + ($null, "two", $null -ne 1)[0]

# Moving the test into the middle of the array evidently cuts the array off
"Test 5: " + ($null, 1 -ne $null, "two").Length

# Moving the test into the middle of the array evidently cuts the array off,
# UNLESS you wrap the test with parens
"Test 6: " + ($null, (1 -ne $null), "two").Length

# The number used in the test is returned for the array value at that index
"Test 7: " + ($null, $null, 8675309 -ne $null)[0]

# The number used in the test is returned for the array value at that index,
# UNLESS you wrap the test with parens
"Test 8: " + ($null, $null, (8675309 -ne $null))[0]

# wrapping the test with parens will break the coalesce
"Test 9: " + ($null, "two", (1 -ne $null))[0]

# if all elements are null, the default value will be the value on the left
# side of the test
"Test 10: " + ($null, $null, 123456789 -ne $null)[0]

# test with an object
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection     
"Test 11: " + ($null, $conn, 1 -ne $null)[0].GetType()
```

Lessons learned:

- The test should go into the very last element of the array
- The test should not be wrapped with parens as it will break the coalesce
- The default value MUST be on the left side of the test, or be hard coded as the second to last item in the array
- We tested with numbers and and a simple object test, so it should work for any type of object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two documentation topics of primary interest here:

- [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays)
- [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)

---

The short of it is that for null-coalescing with your approach to work:

- `-ne $null` must be used as the filter
- and the filter must be applied to the *entire* array

That way, index `[0]` will return the *first non-null* element from the input array.

Since it may not be obvious, let me point out that, as documented in [`about_Operator_Precedence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence):

```
$null, 2, 3 -ne $null # returns array without $nulls: 2, 3
```

is parsed as:

```
($null, 2, 3) -ne $null
```

---

> it does not matter what the number is evidently
>
> `"Test 3: " + ($null, "two", 8675309 -ne $null)[0]`

Test 3 works as expected: `-ne $null` filters out the `$null` elements, so index `0` accesses the first non-null element.

---

> reversing the comparison test breaks the coalesce
>
> `"Test 4: " + ($null, "two", $null -ne 1)[0]`

`-ne 1` returns all elements that aren't `1`, which *includes the `$null` elements*; so accessing index `0` returns `$null` here.

---

> Moving the test into the middle of the array evidently cuts the array off
>
> `"Test 5: " + ($null, 1 -ne $null, "two").Length`

`$null, 1 -ne $null, "two"` is the same as: `($null, 1) -ne ($null, "two"`) and yields `$null, 1`, i.e. *the unmodified LHS*. This is because `-ne` doesn't match any of the LHS elements due the RHS being an *array*, which isn't meaningfully supported.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

All the other tests are just variations of the above.

---

<sup>[1] What happens - obscurely - is that the a RHS array is *stringified* before comparing, so that only LHS elements that match the stringified array are filtered; e.g., `'1 2', 3 -ne 1, 2` results in `@(3)`, because `"$(1, 2)"` results in a string with value `1 2`, which matches the 1st LHS element.</sup>

Comment: TYVM @mklement0, makes me feel better seeing it documented in the operator precedence doc, but that was probably the last place I expected to find it. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @SpaceGhost440. Operator precedence in PowerShell can be tricky, not least because there are so many operators, including `,`, the array-construction operator, itself.