# Changing Data in Columns in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a PowerShell script pulling data in from a CSV. What I am trying to do is "replace" the data in the Account column based on the value. For example, Account 001 = Hardware, Account 002 = Software, etc. The data in the CSV is being pulled from a SQL database so if it would be easier for me to change it in the SQL script, I can do that easily. The Account column in the CSV has 001, 002, etc. I want to change those values to Hardware, Software, etc. Thanks for the help.

```
$Results = import-csv Expenses.csv

$Array = @()       
Foreach($R in $Results)
{
        $Object = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
 
            Account = $R.Account
            Vendor = $R.Desc1
            Item = $R.Desc2
            Amount = $R.Amount
            
 
        }
        $Array += $Object
}

$Array
```

Answer (score 5):

If your CSV looks anything like this:

```
Account,Vendor,Item,Amount
001,Some Vendor,Something expensive, 1
002,Another Vendor,Something cheapish,26
```

you can update without a loop:

```
# create a lookup hashtable where you combine the account values with the wanted replacement
$lookup = @{
    '001' = 'Hardware'
    '002' = 'Software'
    # etcetera
}
# import the csv and update the `Account` column
$Results = Import-Csv D:\Test\Expenses.csv | Select-Object @{Name = 'Account'; Expression = {$lookup[$_.Account]}}, * -ExcludeProperty Account

# display on screen
$Results
# output to (new) csv file
$Results | Export-Csv -Path D:\Test\Expenses_Updated.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
Account  Vendor         Item                Amount
-------  ------         ----                ------
Hardware Some Vendor    Something expensive 1     
Software Another Vendor Something cheapish  26
```

---

As per the comment of [not2qubit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147688/not2qubit) some explanation about the Select-Object statement used.

Because the result should reflect all fields in the csv, where the existing field value named `Account` needs to be replaced, the code uses a [Calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to set the Account field values using whatever was stored in the lookup Hashtable.

This is done with `@{Name = 'Account'; Expression = {$lookup[$_.Account]}}`

Next, all other fields contained in the csv are selected unchanged using the asteriks `*`.

Because we're overwriting the Accound field, but keep its name, the line ends with `-ExcludeProperty Account` in order to remove the **original** Account field in the output.
If we don't do that, PowerShell will show an error: *Select-Object : The property cannot be processed because the property "Account" already exists.*

Comment: I would be great if you could further explain the complicated `Select-Object` component.

Comment: @not2qubit Please see my edit. I hope that explains what is going on in the code.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood what you require correctly, you just want to change "001" to "Hardware" and so on in the object imported by the Import-Csv cmdlet. You can create a [ScriptBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.1) with a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-switch?view=powershell-7.1) that will return a value based off the value you have searched for. I could have recommended a [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.1) here too, but the benefit of a switch over a Hashtable, in this case, is that you can return the value using the default option if it is not specified. For example:

```
$Lookup = {
    Param ([string]$Value)
    
    switch ($Value) {
        "001" { "Hardware" }
        "002" { "Software" }
        default { $Value }
    }
}

$Results = Import-Csv Expenses.csv

foreach($R in $Results)
{
    # Invoke the scriptblock with the named parameter.
    $R.Account = & $Lookup -Value $R.Account
}

# Do stuff with $Results
```

Comment: Nice. If PowerShell only had a null-coalescing operator...

Comment: Well, it's there in PowerShell 7, but not before.

Comment: @Tomalak What is a `null-coalescing operator`, and how would it help here?

Comment: @Ash Can you also show what's in the `Expenses.csv` file?

Comment: It's the file that OP describes as part of their initial question.

Comment: Null-coalescing operator is an expression that returns the left hand side argument if it isn't null. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642435/9164015) for the PowerShell implementation. It would help remove the $Lookup hashtable and simplify the code if we were certain that the account was either `Hardware` or `Software`.